# Upload failed in Wordpress using nextgen plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload, public

I'm using the NextGen Public Uploader plugin, and it works fine on the local server when i try to upload a image, after i uploaded it on a server, it won't work, gives me the next error:

Unable to write to directory /home/vioo6154/public_html/\wp-content\gallery\galerie-retro. Is this directory writable by the server?

thank you very much.

Comment: Your answer might be right there in the error message. Have you checked if the directory is writable?

Comment: check the permissions of the directory you are trying to write to

Comment: the permission is 755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem just replacing the galleries withe the new ones, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things that could prevent your upload from working.

1. Permissions - as it states the permission may state the directory you are trying to upload to is not writable.  Wordpress has a set of standards for files and directories you can find here http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions
2. The second could be ownership.  You will find that most of the time the owner and the group are www-data.  This is dependent on the type of server you are on.  If you are operating on cpanel you are owner and group are going to be the username you use to loginto cpanel.

If you give some more info on your ownership and permissions I can help you better.

Comment: the permission is set to 755, about the ownership.. i'm not familiarized with this. can help me with ownership first?

Comment: Are you using FTP to launch or are you using ssh?

Comment: Ok so everything is based off which FTP Client you are using.  I user CyberDuck for FTP and if I right click on a file and click on "Info" it will show me the "Owner" and the "Group".  Those are what you need to verify are correct.  You then need to verify your permissions http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

just set the file_uploads=1 in the php.ini file and then the uploads will work sequentially with no problems

in your hosting you can have the php.ini you can get this link by check with the info.php link in the server.

eg., www.example.com/info.php

in the info.php the code is given below

and you can search for the php.ini file path and you have to change there

Answer (score 0):

set the file_uploads=1 in the php.ini file and then the uploads will work sequentially with no problems